# How to sync my app with photos

Tags: android

I build custom gallery for photos only. I taking photos from sdcard with this class:

```
public class Photos {
public static final String PHOTO_BUCKET_NAME =
    Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString() + "/DCIM/Camera";
public static final int PHOTO_BUCKET_ID = getBucketId(PHOTO_BUCKET_NAME);

public static int getBucketId(String path) {
    return path.toLowerCase().hashCode();
}

public static List<String> getPhotos(Context context) {
    final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID;
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(c.getCount());
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int dataColumn = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        do {
            String data = c.getString(dataColumn);
            result.add(data);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    return result;
}
```

And set adapter to gallery:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    int GalItemBg;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> photoList;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
        photoList = Photos.getPhotos(c);
        TypedArray typArray = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.GalleryTheme);
        GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.GalleryTheme_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        typArray.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return photoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    } 

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoList.get(position));
        i.setImageBitmap(bm);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80,70));
        i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        i.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

        return i;
    }
}
```

}
There is nothing special. When i run my app, all good it works. After that I launch camera and taking some photos, in this time my app running in background. When I back to my app, I need to see new photos. How to do it?

Tried:
update adapter in onResume method like this:

```
Gallery g;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
}
```

App crashing. May be I do something wrong?

LogCat:

```
02-09 08:12:33.719: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.TabAct}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab} did not call through to super.onResume()
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2516)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab}: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab} did not call through to super.onResume()
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:170)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(LocalActivityManager.java:518)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.onResume(ActivityGroup.java:58)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3763)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 12 more
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab} did not call through to super.onResume()
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3765)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
02-09 08:12:34.129: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: Implement the onresume method in your activity and call this photo utility method of yours to refresh. Am I missing something here? Because the solution is  pretty obvious.

Comment: Thx. I tried this, app crashing. Sorry, i newbie =)

Comment: ok. Thanks for help. That's clear. Doing again, when I resume my app, in gallery appear new photos, but when I click on them, app again crashing =(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call super.onResume in the onResume method.

You can see this in the message of your exception: `android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {ru.home.tabexample/ru.home.tabexample.FirstTab} did not call through to super.onResume()`

The activity base class also uses the onResume methods to reinitialise stuff. If you implement it in your class but leave out the super.onResume() call those initializations in the base class can not be made.

Comment: k. Thanks for help. That's clear. Doing again, when I resume my app, in gallery appear new photos, but when I click on them, app again crashing =(

Comment: @ken As janusz said the crash reason is obvious. You should try what he said. @janusz +1.